# After upgrading from magento 1 to magento 2.3, existing customer can’t login

Tags: magento2.3, magento-upgrade

My site is working fine but existing customer can’t login.
Is ther any way to resolve this isssue??

Comment: Which migration technique have you employed?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 used MD5 Algorithm to store customer passwords whereas in Magento 2, SHA256 Algorithm is made use. So try running this command to upgrade customer' s hash according to the latest algorithm

```
php bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade
```

Comment: after run this command, I got error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given???

Comment: Can you please share the exact error here

Comment: After run php bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade, I got an error:
----Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given in /vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:247
----/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Customer\Console\Command\UpgradeHashAlgorithmCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually upgrade your password_hash using md5 to sha256, Once you are done with migration, run below command:

```
php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade
```

Comment: I am done with migration.

Comment: have you run the above command? after this run indexing.

Comment: after run this command, I got error:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given

Comment: I solve this problem. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286520/after-m1-to-m2-customer-migration-by-command-customerhashupgrade-got-an-err/286521#286521