# After M1 to M2 customer migration by command "customer:hash:upgrade", got an error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode()

Tags: customer, migration

After converted M1 customer to M2 format, run php bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade,  got an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given in /vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:247 
/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Customer\Console\Command\UpgradeHashAlgorithmCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in $version when handling MD5 (version =0) and SHA256 (version=1) password in the hash function.

Override the Hash Command.

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Customer\Console\Command\UpgradeHashAlgorithmCommand" type="MyCode\FixCustomerUpgradeHashAlgorithm\Console\Command\UpgradeHashAlgorithmCommand"/>
    </config>
```

app/code/MyCode/FixCustomerUpgradeHashAlgorithm/Console/Command/UpgradeHashAlgorithmCommand.php

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->collection = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create();
    $this->collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $customerCollection = $this->collection->getItems();
    /** @var $customer Customer */
    foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
        $customer->load($customer->getId());
        if (!$customer->getPasswordHash()) continue;
        if (!$this->encryptor->validateHashVersion($customer->getPasswordHash())) {
            list($hash, $salt, $version) = explode(Encryptor::DELIMITER, $customer->getPasswordHash(), 3);
            $version .= Encryptor::DELIMITER . Encryptor::HASH_VERSION_LATEST;

            $hash = implode(
                Encryptor::DELIMITER,
                [
                    $this->encryptor->hash($salt.$hash),
                    $salt,
                    $version
                ]
            );
            $customer->setPasswordHash($hash);
            $customer->save();
        }
    }
    $output->writeln(".");
    $output->writeln("<info>Finished</info>");
}
```